# Change() doesn't react with class identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do certain action whenever value of one field (all the same class) changes. It doen't work though.

```
$('.payment-amount').change(function () {
        ajax_get_supposed_money_left();
    });
```

I'm not sure why. I do the exactly same action with ID instead of class and everytnig works fine:

```
$('#tripsummary-money_begin').change(function () {
        ajax_get_supposed_money_left();
    });
```

The class is specified correctly, because in my function I use `$('.payment-amount').val()` and it return the correct value. It only doesn't want to work when used with `change()` action.

**EDIT:**

I'm using Yii2, so the part of relevant Html looks like this:

```
DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper_expenses', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
    'widgetBody' => '.container-expenses', // required: css class selector
    'widgetItem' => '.item-expense', // required: css class
    'limit' => 99, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
    'min' => 0, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
    'insertButton' => '.add-item-expense', // css class
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item-expense', // css class
    'model' => $expense_models[0],
    'formId' => 'expense-create-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'amount',
        'category',
        'comment',
    ],
]);
?>
<div class="panel-body container-items">
    <div class="panel-heading font-bold">
        <button type="button" class="pull-left add-item-expense btn btn-success btn-xm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <?= Yii::t('app', 'Add') ?></button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="payments-container" class="panel-body container-expenses"><!-- widgetContainer -->
        <?php foreach ($expense_models as $index => $model): ?>
            <div class="item-expense"><!-- widgetBody -->
                <div>
                    <?php
                    // necessary for update action.
                    if (!$model->isNewRecord) {
                        echo Html::activeHiddenInput($model, "[{$index}]id");
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <?=
                            $form->field($model, "[{$index}]amount")->textInput(['class' => 'form-control payment-amount'])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Amount'))
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <?=
                            $form->field($model, "[{$index}]trip_summary_category_id")->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(TripSummaryCategory::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'), [
                                'class' => 'form-control payment_type',
                            ])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Category'))
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3" >
                            <?=
                            $form->field($model, "[{$index}]comment")->textInput()->label(Yii::t('app', 'Comment'));
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="custom-remove-btn remove-item-expense btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
                    </div><!-- end:row -->
                </div>
                <div class="custom-divider"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your html code

Comment: Make sure you put this in a `$(document).ready` so that the DOM is ready when you attach the `.change()` handler

Comment: @VaTz88 Yes, I have it inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: Can you describe what are you expecting? Change -> when you enter other value in input? or change -> when you focus out from input?

Comment: @xAqweRx When value of the input changes

Comment: Try change `.change` to `.keyup`

Comment: @xAqweRx It didn't change anythig, I don't think keyup is the right solution, because I need to react to change of the input

Comment: Can you post the resultant html, not just the yii code, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisCousins added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer finally. Since there is no .payment-amount class-having fields at the very beginning, the code couldn't be executed the way I wanted. To prevent this I use:

```
$('body').on('change', '.payment-amount', function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
        // rest of code
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

So, according to [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/change/) (first example provided):

> The event handler can be bound to the text input and the select box:
>
> ```
> $( ".target" ).change(function() {
>   alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
> });
> ```
>
> Now when the second option is selected from the dropdown, the 
>   alert is displayed. **It is also displayed if you change the text in the field and then click away.** If the field loses focus without the contents having 
>   changed, though, the event is not triggered.

In example provided, try to type something in the input and then make it lose focus (click outside of it). You will see value typed in the console.

```js
var paymentAmountInputs = $(".payment-amount");

paymentAmountInputs.change(function(evt) { 
    console.log($(this).val()) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="payment-amount" value="0" />
```

Your solution would be using `keydown` if you want to read the input value *on the fly* :

```js
var paymentAmountInputs = $(".payment-amount");

paymentAmountInputs.keydown(function(evt) { 
    console.log($(this).val()) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" class="payment-amount" value="0" />
```

Comment: I undestand, but it doesn't change anything. It looks like it doesn't react to anything.

Comment: What doesn't `change` anything?

Comment: if I have change, if I have keydown, if I have keyup. It doesn't react to anything, console.log is not triggered, nor any funciot or other code I put inside.

Comment: What jQuery version do you use? Could you try to use `.on("change", function(event) { })` instead ?

Comment: I have the newest one, downloaded about 2 weeks ago. I tried both, `.change` and `.on('change')`.